# Translating form_for syntax to simple_form syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, simple-form-for

I have this code within my rails form:

```
  Categories: <%= f.collection_select :tag_ids, Tag.order(:name), :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true} %>
```

This code is working, but I want to use simpleform gem to redesign my form. However, I cannot seem to figure how to 'translate' this code into simple form. Anyone have any idea how? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

If you have a many to many relation you could first try what the default does.

```
<%= f.association :tags %>
```

If the defaults don't work out you can make an explicit collection:

```
<%= f.input :tag_ids, as: :select, collection: Tag.order(:name), label_method: :name, input_html: {multiple: true} %>
# or
<%= f.input :tag_ids, as: :select, collection: Tag.order(:name).pluck(:name, :id), input_html: {multiple: true} %>
```

Alternatively if you define the *Tag#to_label* method you don't have to pass the name of the label method. The *Tag#id* gets used as default value method. If you would like another value specify the method like so: `value_method: :something_else`.

See the [simple_form Usage section](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/simple_form#Usage) (intro, collections and associations).